# How to force a instance attribute to always be a list?

Tags: python, list, properties, wrapper

I have a class that contains many attributes. There is a attribute I want to always be a `list`, that is it cannot be overwritten with anything else and it will always behave like a `list`.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = None
        self.var2 = None
        self.alwaysList = []

sc = SomeClass()
sc.alwaysList.append("Something") # Valid
sc.alwaysList = 5 # Should be invalid
```

Should I write wrapper functions? Should I use `@property`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `@property` and `@alwaysList.setter` to define the behavior when the prop is set. You can strictly enforce a list type in the setter (or test the abstract base class: `isinstance(newVal, collections.Sequence)`), or (maybe more pythonic) take anything that is iterable and convert to list:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = None
        self.var2 = None
        self._alwaysList = []

    @property
    def alwaysList(self):
        return self._alwaysList

    @alwaysList.setter
    def alwaysList(self, newVal):
        ''' a little more forgiving of input '''
        try:
            self._alwaysList = list(newVal)

        except TypeError:
            # print warning or raise
            print("alwaysList must be iterable: {} is not iterable".format(newVal))



sc = SomeClass()
sc.alwaysList.append("Something") # Valid
sc.alwaysList = 90                # error alwaysList must be iterable: 90 is not iterable
sc.alwaysList = "somthing"        # string is iterable -- convert to list
sc.alwaysList                     # ['s', 'o', 'm', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Using above is more flexible — you can pass in anything that is iterable like `sc.alwaysList = range(10)` while still always having a list in the property.